SQL query performance drops significantly with large datasets and multiple joins
I have a SQL query when joining several large tables. My database consists of millions of rows across the users, orders and transactions table. Here is the query
    SELECT u.name, COUNT(o.id) AS order_count
    FROM users u
    JOIN orders o ON u.id = o.user_id
    JOIN transactions t ON o.id = t.order_id
    WHERE t.status = 'completed'
    GROUP BY u.name
    HAVING order_count > 10;


I ensured that there are indexes on all the necessary fields. users.id, orders.user_id and transactions.order_id. However the query becomes significantly slower as the dataset size increases.
The order table is approximately 5 million rows.
The transactions table is approximately 10 million rows.
The database is running on MySQL 8.
What optimization techniques or query restructuring could help improve performance in this case?

Please share the output of the explain and the details of all indexes created on these tables.

'I ensured that there are indexes on all the necessary fields.' - I guess the optimiser thinks otherwise. Please publish the table definitions as text with the explain. and the long response is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/select-optimization.html

The best way to get high quality help with this kind of thing is to create an SQL Fiddle one one of the many available external websites.  Then somebody smart is likely to just jump in with a useful answer

It would be useful if you told us what you are trying to achieve.

Please read this then [edit] your question to provide necessary details for us to help you.

This delays the name lookup until after the GROUP BY
SELECT  u.name
        ot.order_count
    FROM (
        SELECT  o.user_id,
                COUNT(*) AS order_count
          FROM orders o
          JOIN  transactions t  ON o.id = t.order_id
          WHERE  t.status = 'completed'
          GROUP BY  o.user_id
          HAVING  order_count > 10 ) AS ot
    LEFT JOIN users u  ON u.id = ot.user_id;

This is 'composite' and 'covering' and useful for the transaction lookup.  And the columns are in the optimal order:
INDEX(status, order_id)

If these suggestions do not help enough, please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables and EXPLAIN SELECT ....

Why use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN ?

If the name is known to be present, the use of LEFT probably does not matter.

Try to create thoses indexes, they are covering...
CREATE INDEX X001 ON transactions (status, order_id);

CREATE INDEX X002 ON orders (user_id, id);

CREATE INDEX X003 ON users (id, name);

Single columns indexes are good if the query returns few rows without any aggregation.
